# Flutter touch events on inidividual letters of a string

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to detect touch events on individual letters of a string.

For example, if the string is "HELLO", I need to distinguish between tapping on "H" or the "O". The actual strings will be longer than that, around 500 characters.

Naively, I thought about wrapping all characters them into individual Text widgets. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example where I have create a sample example via which you will get an idea for you implementation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
 

  List<String> sampleStrings = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', "O"];

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Your heading'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 80,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: sampleStrings.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('This is the tapped letter : ${sampleStrings[index]}');
              },
              child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${sampleStrings[index]}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  )),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a Gesture Detector. but even with that you may need to use individual letters as separate Gesture Detectors.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html